# Replace array item with another one without mutating state

Tags: reactjs, state, redux, mutation

This is how example of my state looks:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
 contents: [ {}, {}, {}, etc.. ],
 meta: {}
}
```

I need to be able and somehow replace an item inside contents array knowing its index, I have tried:

```
      return {
        ...state,
        contents: [
          ...state.contents[action.meta.index],
          {
            content_type: 7,
            content_body: {
              album_artwork_url: action.payload.data.album.images[1].url,
              preview_url: action.payload.data.preview_url,
              title: action.payload.data.name,
              subtitle: action.payload.data.artists[0].name,
              spotify_link: action.payload.data.external_urls.spotify
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

where `action.meta.index` is index of array item I want to replace with another contents object, but I believe this just replaces whole array to this one object I'm passing. I also thought of using `.splice()` but that would just mutate the array?

Comment: Also, take a look at React's Immutability helpers - https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html
They are not as hard to use as they look and really makes your code easier to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Splice` mutate the array you need to use `Slice` . And you also need to `concat` the sliced piece .

```
return Object.assign({}, state,  {
         contents:
          state.contents.slice(0,action.meta.index)
          .concat([{
            content_type: 7,
            content_body: {
              album_artwork_url: action.payload.data.album.images[1].url,
              preview_url: action.payload.data.preview_url,
              title: action.payload.data.name,
              subtitle: action.payload.data.artists[0].name,
              spotify_link: action.payload.data.external_urls.spotify
            }
          }])
          .concat(state.contents.slice(action.meta.index + 1))
  }
```

Comment: Edited .I guess you are trying to send the entire state , with content value changed. So, use Object.assign to send new state , and if there are multiple sources for same key in Object.assign , last source wins .

Comment: Thnx. saved my life.

Answer (score 24):

Note that `Array.prototype.map()` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) does **not** mutate the original array so it provides another option:

```
 const INITIAL_STATE = {
   contents: [ {}, {}, {}, etc.. ],
   meta: {}
 }

 // Assuming this action object design
 {
   type: MY_ACTION,
   data: {
     // new content to replace
   },
   meta: {
     index: /* the array index in state */,
   }
 }

 function myReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
   switch (action.type) {
     case MY_ACTION: 
       return {
         ...state,
         // optional 2nd arg in callback is the array index
         contents: state.contents.map((content, index) => {
           if (index === action.meta.index) {
             return action.data
           }

           return content
         })
       }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Definitely the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 13):

Just to build on @sapy's answer which is the correct one. I wanted to show you another example of how to change a property of an object inside an array in Redux without mutating the state.

I had an array of `orders` in my state. Each `order` is an object containing many properties and values. I however, only wanted to change the `note` property. So some thing like this

```
let orders = [order1_Obj, order2_obj, order3_obj, order4_obj];
```

where for example `order3_obj = {note: '', total: 50.50, items: 4, deliverDate: '07/26/2016'};`

So in my Reducer, I had the following code:

```
return Object.assign({}, state,
{
  orders: 
    state.orders.slice(0, action.index)
    .concat([{
      ...state.orders[action.index],
      notes: action.notes 
    }])
    .concat(state.orders.slice(action.index + 1))
   })
```

So essentially, you're doing the following:

1) Slice out the array before `order3_obj` so `[order1_Obj, order2_obj]`

2) Concat (i.e add in) the edited `order3_obj` by using the three dot `...` spread operator and the particular property you want to change (i.e `note`)

3) Concat in the rest of the orders array using `.concat` and `.slice` at the end `.concat(state.orders.slice(action.index + 1))` which is everything after `order3_obj` (in this case `order4_obj` is the only one left).

Comment: Thank you so much! Super helpful explanation

Comment: this helped me so much.  ty for this