# How can I replace the value in an array using redux?

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm trying to overwrite a specific value in my Redux state which is an array. I have gotten the index already and also the value of the new text. I'm just not sure about the best way of overwriting the previous text. Here is my reducer so far. The UPDATE_LINK is the one I'm having trouble with.

```
export function linkList(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_LINK': 
            var text = action.text;
            console.log('Adding link');
            console.log(text);
            return {
                ...state,
                links: [text, ...state.links]
            };
        case 'DELETE_LINK':
            var index = action.index;
            console.log('Deleting link');
            return {
                ...state,
                links: [
                    ...state.links.slice(0, index),
                    ...state.links.slice(index + 1)
                ],
            };
        case 'UPDATE_LINK':
            var index = action.index;
            var newText = action.newText;
            console.log(action.newText);
            console.log(action.index);
            return {
                ...state,
                // How do I update text? 
            }
        default: 
            return state;
    }
};

export default linkList;
```

Comment: nice code formatting :+1:

Comment: you can use the same logic of delete and add the updated link there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace array item with another one without mutating state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35362460/replace-array-item-with-another-one-without-mutating-state)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [Array.protoype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return the existing entries where available and a new entry where the index matches:

```
var index = action.index;
var newText = action.newText;
return {
    ...state,
    links: state.links.map((existingLink, currentIndex) => index === currentIndex ? newText : existingLink)
}
```

Or, following your existing `DELETE_LINK` logic:

```
return {
    ...state,
    links: [
        ...state.links.slice(0, index),
        newText,
        ...state.links.slice(index + 1)
    ],
};
```

Comment: You may also want to look at some of the information in the ["Structuring Reducers'](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) section of the Redux docs.  In particular, see the ["Immutable Update Patterns"](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) page.