# Updating Object Property in Reducer without Mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I feel like my reducer should be working, but it keeps insisting that I'm mutating the state.

> Uncaught Error: A state mutation was detected inside a dispatch, in the path: `output.outputList.0.composition`. Take a look at the reducer(s) handling the action {"type":"SET_OUTPUT_COMPOSITION",

I posted something similar a couple hours ago with no answers, but I figured my redux state was too complicated.  This is my simplified version and I'm still getting mutate errors.. what am I doing wrong?  should I not be using a class in my redux state?  should i be using some sort of immutable library? please help me.

My Initial Redux State

```
output: {
    outputList: [], //composed of Output class objects
    position: 0
  }
```

Output Class

```
class Output {

  constructor(output) {
      this.id = output.id;
      this.composition = output.getComposition();
      this.outputObj = output;
      this.name = output.name;
      this.url = output.getUrl();    
  }
}

export default Output;
```

Reducer for updating property

```
case types.SET_OUTPUT_COMPOSITION: {
      let outputListCopy = Object.assign([], [...state.outputList]);
      outputListCopy[state.position].composition = action.composition;
      return Object.assign({}, state, {outputList: outputListCopy});
```

Action

```
export function setOutputComposition(comp) {
 return { type: types.SET_OUTPUT_COMPOSITION, composition: comp}
}
```

Comment: Can you include your action

Comment: @DavidBradshaw added action for you ty

Comment: I found the answer I needed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35362460/replace-array-item-with-another-one-without-mutating-state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) does not deep copy the objects in your original list:

```
let outputListCopy = Object.assign([], [...state.outputList]);
```

It is a shallow copy, therefore

```
outputListCopy[state.position].composition = action.composition;
```

You are actually mutating previous state objects, as you said in your comment there are several ways to work around this, using slice/splice to create new instance of the array, etc.

You can also take a look at using [ImmutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/), in general I would say storing classes in the redux store makes the thing a bit hard to understand, I tend to favor simple structures that can be easily inspected with redux-tools.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from `dispatch`. So it not even getting as far as the `reducer`. I expect it does not like you using `class` to define `output`. Instead just do `const output ={ ... }`.

Comment: ah i was hoping you would be correct.. i turned the class into a psuedo class where it's a function that just returns an object with the same properties but still getting the same error.  Also when I put a break point in the reducer, I see it go all the way through, it gets the same error though when once it tries to return the new state as did before.

Comment: What happens if you send a string instead?